737 ALT DISAGREE Non-Normal Checklist questions
1 choose IAS DISAGREE alert is not shown, and then:
2 Verify all altimeters are set to correct barometric setting.
3 choose DISAGREE alert stays illuminated:
and here is the thing, WHY 4 Standby altimeter is available?
How to know standby altimeter is available?


That statement is a reminder that you have the standby altimeter available as a resource.  It's not accurate enough to allow you to stay in RVSM airspace, but it may be a tie-breaker between the disagreeing instruments.  And for a crew that is so focused on the displays and wanting to sort our what should be believed and what should be ignored, that sort of a reminder may be what's needed in the stress of the moment.

This is a great human factors answer!
